# Graph Database Structure

Tags: database, graph-databases, rexster, tinkerpop-blueprint, sparksee

I will use Sparsity (former name is DEX) graph database in my case. But haven't got experience related with graph databases. I have read several articles, many of them suggest several things(Rexster server, REST API, Bluprint etc.) in order to use those DB-s.
So, is it necessary to use Server(i.e Rexster) for those DB-s? And what Configurations I must do in order to do DB operations. I will use Java as a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary purpose of Rexster is to provide a way for non-JVM languages to communicate with a Blueprints Graph.  I would say that it is also useful for centralizing access to graph traversals as a service with or without the JVM in mind.  It is not explicitly required to use the TinkerPop stack or any specific graph database implementation of Blueprints.  If you are building a JVM application you may choose to simply reference TinkerPop libraries and utilize them directly as dependencies.

Comment: I downloaded "sparksee 5.1". As I understood from your answer, I can just add required jar files to my IDE for given DB and then I can use it.
I must define REST API explicitly or it will be defined implicitly?

Comment: If you are building a java application then add the required jars to your ide.  if you want to use sparksee behind Rexster to get a REST API to work with then you will need to download Rexster separately and copy the sparksee jars to Rexster's path (i.e. `/lib` or `/ext` directory) and then configure rexster to expose the Sparksee in its routes. sparksee has documentation for Rexster configuration here: http://sparsity-technologies.com/UserManual/ThirdPartyTools.html